# Filter elements with AND condition instead of OR using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, conditional-statements, filtering

I have got code (thanks to @CarstenLøvboAndersen) for filtering element based on OR condition and I need change it to condition AND.

At this moment when I choose red and blue result are every elements that has class red or blue. I need it change to condition AND so when I choose red and blue, result must be only elements that meet both conditions. That's mean only elements where class contains red and blue together.

```js
$('.selector button').click(function() {
  $('.selector input').prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
});

$('.selector input').change(function() {
  $('.filterelements div').hide();
  $('.selector input:checked').each(function() {
    $('.filterelements div.' + $(this).val()).show();

  })


  if ($('.selector input:checked').length == 0) {
    $('.filterelements div').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.filterelements {
  width: 210px;
}

.red,
.green,
.blue,
.redgreen,
.redblue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff2600;
}

.green {
  background: #a5de00;
}

.blue {
  background: #0087ff;
}

.redgreen {
  background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(165, 222, 0, 1) 100%);
}

.redblue {
  background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 135, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="selector">
    <button type="button" name="all">Show all</button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="red" value="red">red
    <input type="checkbox" name="blue" value="blue">blue
    <input type="checkbox" name="green" value="green">green
  </div>



  <hr />
  <div class="filterelements">
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="blue" rel="color:blue"></div>
    <div class="redgreen red green" rel="color:red|color:green"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="redblue red blue" rel="color:red|color:blue"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
$('.selector input').change(function() {
  var classes = "";
  $(".filterelements div").hide();
  $(".selector input:checked").each(function() {
    classes += "." + $(this).val();
  });
  $(".filterelements div"+classes).show();
});
```

This will take the values from each `checked input` use that to generate a collection of the classes that each div must have in order to be shown.

**Demo**

```js
$('.selector button').click(function() {
  $('.selector input').prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
});

$('.selector input').change(function() {
  var classes = "";
  $(".filterelements div").hide();
  $(".selector input:checked").each(function() {
    classes += "." + $(this).val();
  });
  $(".filterelements div"+classes).show();
});
```

```css
.filterelements {
  width: 210px;
}

.red,
.green,
.blue,
.redgreen,
.redblue {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff2600;
}

.green {
  background: #a5de00;
}

.blue {
  background: #0087ff;
}

.redgreen {
  background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(165, 222, 0, 1) 100%);
}

.redblue {
  background: rgb(255, 38, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 38, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 135, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="selector">
    <button type="button" name="all">Show all</button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="red" value="red">red
    <input type="checkbox" name="blue" value="blue">blue
    <input type="checkbox" name="green" value="green">green
  </div>



  <hr />
  <div class="filterelements">
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="blue" rel="color:blue"></div>
    <div class="redgreen red green" rel="color:red|color:green"></div>
    <div class="green" rel="color:green"></div>
    <div class="red" rel="color:red"></div>
    <div class="redblue red blue" rel="color:red|color:blue"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```